# How to ORDER BY DESC with JOIN statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT
        result.ip,
        ips.ipStatus,
        result.quantity,
        result.clickDates,
    FROM
        ips
    INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                visits.ip,
                count(visits.ip) AS quantity,
                GROUP_CONCAT(clicks.clickDate) AS clickDates,
            FROM
                visits
            INNER JOIN
                clicks 
                    ON visits.id = clicks.id 
            WHERE
                clicks.clickDate BETWEEN 1 AND 10 
            GROUP BY
                visits.ip 
            ORDER BY
                null
        ) AS result 
            ON ips.ip = result.ip LIMIT 6, 2
```

It produce the result table like this:

```
   ip    |    status    |    quantity    |       date 

1.1.1.1        ok               3            555, 557, 558
2.2.2.2        ok               1            657
```

My date is storing in .ms (BIGINT). My goal is to `ORDER BY` date `DESC`. I want to latest ips will be at the top. So I'm trying to change `ORDER BY` on  `ORDER BY clicks.clickDate DESC`. But it gives me an error:

> Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in GROUP BY clause and
>   contains nonaggregated column

So I Have two questions:

Is it possible to `ORDER BY` if I use `GROUP_CONCAT` on clicks.clickDate column?
Maybe there is a way to show only the last value after `GROUP_CONCAT` on clicks.clickDate?

Comment: Delete that `ORDER BY` clause, which doesn't even belong there.  If you want to add an `ORDER BY` to the outer query, then do so, but use only something which appears in the outer `SELECT`.  Other than this, your query looks fine to me.

Comment: I did so, and it doesn't work properly. Look at this please http://prntscr.com/leoj2w

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to add `order by` in `GROUP_CONCAT` and add one column `MAX(clicks.clickDate)` to get `clickDate` of max in the group, for main query `order by`.

```
SELECT
    result.ip,
    ips.ipStatus,
    result.quantity,
    result.clickDates,
FROM
    ips
INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            visits.ip,
            count(visits.ip) AS quantity,
            GROUP_CONCAT(clicks.clickDate ORDER BY clicks.clickDate desc) AS clickDates,
            MAX(clicks.clickDate) maxDt
        FROM
            visits
        INNER JOIN
            clicks 
                ON visits.id = clicks.id 
        WHERE
            clicks.clickDate BETWEEN 1 AND 10 
        GROUP BY
            visits.ip 
    ) AS result 
        ON ips.ip = result.ip 
ORDER BY maxDt DESC
LIMIT 6, 2
```

Comment: in this way it will ORDER dates inside the group_concat. But I need to ORDER BY date in result table

Comment: @Nastro Becasue it order by string value  `10` smaller than `2`

Answer (score 1):

Try ordering by the *greatest* click date in each record.  Note that we need to *cast* the text date numerical value to an actual integer, so that sorting will work properly.

```
SELECT
    r.ip,
    i.ipStatus,
    r.quantity,
    r.clickDates,
FROM ips i
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        visits.ip,
        count(visits.ip) AS quantity,
        GROUP_CONCAT(clicks.clickDate ORDER BY clicks.clickDate desc) AS clickDates,
        MAX(CAST clicks.clickDate AS UNSIGNED) maxDt
    FROM
        visits
    INNER JOIN
        clicks 
            ON visits.id = clicks.id 
    WHERE
        clicks.clickDate BETWEEN 1 AND 10 
    GROUP BY
        visits.ip 
) r
    ON i.ip = r.ip 
ORDER BY maxDt DESC
LIMIT 6, 2;
```

Comment: thank you for your help. D-Shih was a little bit earlier with the same solution.